# Eeeek! Blue featured counter missing on sites' main page

Tags: bug, status-completed, bountied-tab

Observe. When you visit a site's *questions* page (ex. [www.stackoverflow.com/questions](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions)) the blue counter on the "featured" tab appears as it should:

[image]

But when you visit a site's main page, not the /questions url (ex. [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)), it disappears:

[image]

What's up, devs?

Further info: the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/*/stackoverflow.com) shows that this wasn't a bug on Aug 1st this year:

[image]

---

Editorial notes: Bug posted for [TildalWave](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/63964/tildalwave). Blame the "Eeeek" on Shog; I promised I'd include it. ;)

Comment: "Eeeek"? Check. Free-hand circles? Check. Dropshadows? Aww...

Comment: @Shog9 If you can do better on Mac Paintbrush, you're welcome to edit ;P

Comment: It's been red for me occasionally (recently)!

Comment: I'm on it! Worry not!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is being fixed and it should be out in a few hours with the next deployment.

Comment: Brilliant! You guys are ninja-quick :)

Comment: Consider marking this "status-completed"

Answer (score 7):

Looking at [the WayBack machine](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://stackoverflow.com), it looks like this bug was introduced between [September 4](http://web.archive.org/web/20130904001635/https://stackoverflow.com/) and [September 9](http://web.archive.org/web/20130909211240/https://stackoverflow.com/)

9/4
[image: 4 Sept]

9/9
[image: 9 Sept]

Comment: -1 No freehand cycle.